# Strange null bytes in CN from openssl req

Tags: debian, ssl, openssl

I need to send CSR (certificate signing request) to the SSL authority for our wildcard domain SSL certificate. I see strange values in the CN (common name) field, for example `CN=\x00*\x00.\x00e\x00x\x00a\x00m\x00p\x00l\x00e\x00.\x00c\x00o\x00m`. If I generate non-wildcard CSR the CN value is as expected: `CN=www.example.com`.

Why are there the `\x00` characters in the CN in CSR for the wildcard domain?

Is it OK, will everything (HTTPS) work properly?

---

I'm on Debian stable (Wheezy), the openssl package version is 1.0.1e-2+deb7u11.

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

This is how I generated the CSR:

```
$ openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout wildcard.key -out wildcard.csr
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
.....................................+++
.......................................+++
writing new private key to 'wildcard.key'
-----
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:CZ
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:
Locality Name (eg, city) []:
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:*.example.com
Email Address []:

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:
An optional company name []:
```

This is the information about the certificate:

```
$ openssl req -text -noout -verify -in wildcard.csr
verify OK
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 0 (0x0)
        Subject: C=CZ, ST=Some-State, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN=\x00*\x00.\x00e\x00x\x00a\x00m\x00p\x00l\x00e\x00.\x00c\x00o\x00m
        Subject Public Key Info:
...
```

Comment: More important question.  **Why are you using a version of OpenSSL that is vulerable to Heartbleed?**

Comment: @Ramhound: this is Debian stable with all packages up to date (`openssl (1.0.1e-2+deb7u11)` from 15 Jun 2014). The openssl package is patched with Heartbleed fix: https://www.debian.org/security/2014/dsa-2896

Comment: That isn't what the output says though.  It says OpenSSL was built in Feb 2014 2 months before the patch was released.  If your positive its patch then thats good enough for me. Trying to do the entire internet a service :-)

Comment: Confirmed, my wheezy boxes are running the same build and version listed above, and they're patched for heart bleed

Comment: What is the *string_mask* you have set in your openssl configuration? It should be `MASK:0x2002` (printableSring and UTF8String).

Comment: @user1039462 Oh, I forgot about this question. Yes, I found later it was something around this - `string_mask` in openssl.conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `openssl.conf` is option `string_mask`. When it is set to `default`. then the CN can be encoded using BMPString (if I remember correctly) and this produces the `\x00`s.

Today (openssl.conf says "PKIX recommendation after 2004") the value should be set to `utf8only`: `string_mask = utf8only`. Then CN then looks "normally":

```
Subject: C=AU, ST=Some-State, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN=*.example.com
```